# Probabilities of calling with Cell phones

Tags: probability

Cell phones perform transfers as they move from cell to cell. During a call, a phone can make zero transfers ($H0$), a transfer ($H1$) or more of a transfer ($H2$). Additionally, each call is ¨long¨ (L)if it lasts more than three minutes or ¨shorter¨ (C) if it lasts less. The following table describes the probabilities of each of the calls

[image]

1- A is the event: The call is long or there are at least two transfers

2- B is the event: The call is short.

3- C is the event: The call had a transfer

a) What is the probability of A?

b) Are B and C independent? Justify

Could you indicate if my solution are right:

a) P = $(1/15 + 2/15+3/15) + (3/15+1/15) - 3/15$

$P = 7/15$

b) B and C are not independent, because when the call is short, it could have a transfer.

Answer (score 1):

For part b), recall that two events are independent iff $P(B \cap C) = P(B)P(C)$.

In this case $P(B \cap C) = 4/15$ and $P(B)P(C) = 9/15*4/15$ which is not equal to $P(B \cap C)$. Therefore the events are NOT independent. So you are correct.

Edit: We get the relationship $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ to prove independence between two variables from $P(A|B) = P(A)$... (given B, the probability of A happening is the same regardless: the definition of independence).

$P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B) = P(A)$ so $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B).$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks to you, your explanation was wery good :)
How about $a)$, Is my answer ok?

Comment: Ooopps we are wrong,
$prob(B∩C) = 3/15$ The call is short and the call had a transfer,
$prob(B)prob(C) = (5/15+3/15+1/15)*(2/15+3/15) = 3/15$
Thus $B$ and $C$ are independent!

Comment: a) Was not right. $P(A) = P(L \cup H_2) = P(L) + P(H_2) - P(L \cap H_2)$. You forgot to subtract 3/15.

Comment: Oh good catch, but I guess I misunderstood the question, does $H_2$ not count as a transfer?

Comment: $H2$ is more than a transfer, it means {2,3,4...n} transfers ;)

Comment: Yes, but is $P(C) = P(H_1) + P(H_2)$?

Comment: $P(C)$ is the call has only a transfer, thus $(2/15 + 3/15)$